# C# Filling datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

When I fill datagridview with list of objects
I can not sort columns

However, I fill the same datagridview with datatable
I can sort columns

How i can sort it when i work with both of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way I know to do this is to derive from `BindingList<T>` and implement the sorting functionality.  I've been using a variation of the class in the following link for some time.  Works great!

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/12eb59d3-e687-4e36-93ab-bf6741954d39/

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to a DataTable. Probably not as clean and efficient as implementing `BindingList<T>`, but it works. Taken from... Lord knows where; not original. Refactored a bit.

To use:

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = GetFromDatabase();  // fake method of your choosing
DataTable dataTable = ToDataTable(myObjects);
yourDataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
```

ToDataTable and other methods:

```
        public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            var tb = new DataTable(typeof (T).Name);
            PropertyInfo[] props = typeof (T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
            {
                Type t = GetCoreType(prop.PropertyType);
                tb.Columns.Add(prop.Name, t);
            }

            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                var values = new object[props.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                }

                tb.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            return tb;
        }

        public static Type GetCoreType(Type t)
        {
            if (t != null && IsNullable(t))
            {
                if (!t.IsValueType)
                {
                    return t;
                }
                else
                {
                    return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return t;
            }
        }

        public static bool IsNullable(Type t)
        {
            return !t.IsValueType || (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>));
        }
```